# Invoke AzureML Batch Endpoint from ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, endpoint, azure-sdk-python, azure-python-sdk

We have deployed our ML pipeline (using SDKV2) on batch endpoints using **PipelineComponentBatchDeployment**. This pipeline takes multiple arguments (all of str type). How can we trigger or invoke the endpoint with different arguments from with ADF.

Previously, with azureml sdkv1, we use to publish the pipelines, in adf we used to have **"Machine Learning Execution"** activity that would invoke the pipeline with different arguments, like shown below:
[image]

But now (with sdkv2) we have endpoints like this:
[image]

On checking the Pipeline Component, we see this:
[image]

Is there a way to see what arguments the pipeline takes? like in sdkv1.

How do we use adf to invoke the endpoint with different inputs.

Thanks,

Comment: How you created this component? provide the code you used to create this component.

Comment: I have given the solution. I you want to send the string literal or custom inputs to your endpoint, you may try to write custom scoring script and use that for deployment. You can check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-batch-scoring-script?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-azure-data-factory?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=mi

Also, its possible to send inputs that are just str using Literals: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-batch-endpoints-jobs.md#create-jobs-with-literal-inputs

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the given documentation, to invoke **Batch endpoints** in Azure **Data Factory**, you need to use **Web activity**. Follow the steps below:

First, you need to have a token for authorization. Run the following commands in Azure CLI and get the token:

```
az login
az account get-access-token --resource https://ml.azure.com --query "accessToken" --output tsv
```

[image]

You will get the token; copy it to any editor and add the `Bearer`  word to it like below.

[image]

Make sure you give space between the token and the `Bearer` word.

For more information about authorization, refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-authenticate-batch-endpoint?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli).

Now, open Data Factory and add a Web activity. In the **Parameters** tab, create a new parameter called `aad_token` as `SecureString` type and paste the token created with bearer in the default field.

[image]

Next, configure details like below in the **Settings** tab.

**URL**: `https://xyx.centralindia.inference.ml.azure.com/jobs`

**Method**: `POST`

**Body**:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "InputData": {
           "credit_dataset": {
               "JobInputType" : "UriFolder",
               "Uri": "https://jgsml4897076647.blob.core.windows.net/azureml-blobstore-f218745d-63e0-4947-bdaf-493fef6422ae/modelDataCollector/jgsml-cyxkp/credit-defaults-model-1/model_inputs/"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I have given the input type as folder and passed the blob URL folder path to data.

Usually, the batch endpoints take a list of paths as input, as defined in the scoring script.

See this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-model-deployments?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#create-a-batch-deployment) for a sample scoring script that takes a list of paths.

In the **Headers**, give **Authorization** as the pipeline token variable you have created.

[image]

Next, run the activity, and it will start the batch job.

[image]

Regarding passing literal strings, it is not supported in batch endpoints according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-batch-azure-data-factory?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=mi) provided for Data Factory.

> `endpoint_input_type`: The type of the input data you are providing. Currently, batch endpoints support folders (`UriFolder`) and files (`UriFile`). Defaults to `UriFolder`.